# Machine translation transformer with context

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, transformer-model, machine-translation

I'm working on a transformer for seq2seq translation that has the typical encoder-decoder structure. I want to include examples of similar sentences and their translations in the prompt (few-shot) but I could only find guides that just translate one sentence to another without other context. Are there any best practices for including examples as context for translation transformers? Should they go in the decoder or encoder?

I currently feed an input sentence `source_sentence` to the encoder and start generating the translation by feeding a start token `<start>` to the decoder until an end token `<end>` is produced.

Should my encoder input be something like this:

```
example_sentence1
<start> example_translation1 <end>

example_sentence2
<start> example_translation2 <end>

source_sentence
```

Or alternatively should my decoder input be:

```
example_sentence1
<start> example_translation1 <end>

example_sentence2
<start> example_translation2 <end>

source_sentence
<start>
```

Neither really feels right. Are there other options?

Comment: This would only work if the model is trained with some sort of prompting, like ChatGPT, StableLM or HuggingAgents . Most probably not the typical off-the-shelf MT model.

Comment: @alvas I'm looking to train my own model from scratch and include the examples already in training phase. I find the suitable examples via embedding search.

Answer (score 0):

You looking for the NLP task "Context Aware NMT". There is some work in the field.

Take a look at this research: [A study of BERT for context-aware neural machine translation](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10994-021-06070-y)

---

If you want to create your own model without using the context inside the prompt.

You can train a BART-like model, and custom the input tags. Hopefully, with the right dataset, the model will understand how to use utilize the context.

Conceptual input vector:  `[ <TAG> context_sen1 <TAG> context_sen2 <SOS> sen3 <EOS> ]`
Conceptual output vector: `[ <SOS> translation <EOS> ]`